# Geoserver exception when requesting paged results: Failed to get property: boundedBy

Tags: geoserver, wfs, error, getfeature

Any clues as to what might be going wrong here?

We are running the following Geoserver:

```
GeoServer Version
2.22.2
Git Revision
78e7383a361356dabfc16b992ebcb0d9e623b831
Build Date
17-Feb-2023 17:46
GeoTools Version
28.2 (rev 558cedba96f8d4c593a362982ce55b7a9e6942dc)
GeoWebCache Version
1.22.1 (rev 1.22.x/b01a7c3999377584b38466ade2f378bf744fb7d0)
The following request returns an exception.
```

It returns an exception when we ask it for paged results by adding a startIndex in the GetFeature request.

```
<GetFeature version="2.0.0" service="WFS" outputFormat="GML32" startIndex="0" count="10" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/geometry.xsd">
    <Query typeNames="org373:Meerssen_verblijfsobjecten">
        <fes:Filter>
            <fes:Intersects>
                <fes:ValueReference>geom</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Polygon srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#28992">
                    <gml:exterior>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:posList xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">14926.000 619922.000 291082.000 619922.000 291082.000 305108.000 14926.000 305108.000 14926.000 619922.000</gml:posList>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:exterior>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </fes:Intersects>
        </fes:Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

Results in:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 https://nedglobe-devng.cadac.com/services/ngservices/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
        <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds</ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

This request but without the a startIndex returns the requested data correctly.

The Geoserver log tells us the following:

```
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://geoserver-ngservices-devng.westeurope.azurecontainer.io:8080/services/ngservices/geoserver/
    count = 1000
    outputFormat = GML32
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    startIndex = 0
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@410b3bad (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: [ geom intersects POLYGON ((14926 619922, 291082 619922, 291082 305108, 14926 305108, 14926 619922)) ], abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{http://org373}Meerssen_verblijfsobjecten]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: null, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        abstractSelectionClause = [ geom intersects POLYGON ((14926 619922, 291082 619922, 291082 305108, 14926 305108, 14926 619922)) ]
        typeNames[0] = {http://org373}Meerssen_verblijfsobjecten
        filter = [ geom intersects POLYGON ((14926 619922, 291082 619922, 291082 305108, 14926 305108, 14926 619922)) ]
12 May 13:50:08 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
12 May 13:50:08 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:218)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:184)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingVisitorDispatch.walk(BindingVisitorDispatch.java:65)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingVisitorDispatch.walk(BindingVisitorDispatch.java:45)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingPropertyExtractor.properties(BindingPropertyExtractor.java:92)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.populateChildren(Encoder.java:767)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.startEncoding(Encoder.java:727)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:662)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:553)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML32OutputFormat.encode(GML32OutputFormat.java:155)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.write(GML3OutputFormat.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:199)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestFilter.process(RequestFilter.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter.doFilter(RemoteAddrFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter.doFilter(RemoteIpFilter.java:937)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter.doFilter(RemoteIpFilter.java:994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while computing reprojected bounds
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:181)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.getBounds(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:98)
    at org.geotools.wfs.bindings.WFSParsingUtils.FeatureCollectionType_getProperty(WFSParsingUtils.java:88)
    at org.geotools.wfs.v2_0.FeatureCollectionTypeBinding.getProperty(FeatureCollectionTypeBinding.java:102)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:101)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.data.transform.TransformFeatureCollection.openIterator(TransformFeatureCollection.java:130)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:47)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:31)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.openIterator(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:93)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:66)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.getBounds(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:166)
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: are all the geometries valid? and what projection is your data stored in? This seems to be a reprojection issue, but the fact it works with out the start index is odd - do you have a primary key defined on the data source?

Comment: Maybe GeoServer needs help for sorting the results. Try adding also sortby into the paged request.

Comment: @user30184 - it should use primary key order if no sort is provided

Comment: Right, and it seems that missing PK should yield a different error about missing natural sorting order https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/AM9P190MB12354EC4F4F88257AFEFBA1AB2299%40AM9P190MB1235.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/#msg37287105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments below my question made me check the table. The problem was indeed a missing primary key on the table.